# Err 1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:'70,40,77,28,23,72,82,38,29'

Tags: mysql

When I execute this function like this:

[image]

This is my function defined:

```
CREATE FUNCTION kyf_getFormationComat(heroSdIds VARCHAR(128), uid VARCHAR(128))
RETURNS INT(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE comat INT(11);
    SET comat = (SELECT SUM(a.comat) FROM ky_heroinfo a WHERE a.uid = uid AND a.staticdata_id in (heroSdIds));
    RETURN comat;
END
```

Comment: Could it be related to your use of double quotes in the function call? (i.e. maybe you should use single quotes)

Comment: i just use single quotes, the same error

Comment: If `staticdata_id` is a number, what you're trying to do will never work. CSV strings are an awful format to do database searches.

Comment: do you have some suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heroSdIds` is a string, therefore you can't use `IN()` in your `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.comat) FROM ky_heroinfo a 
    WHERE a.uid = uid AND a.staticdata_id in (heroSdIds)
```

In condition:

```
a.staticdata_id in (heroSdIds)
```

actually gives you:

```
a.staticdata_id in ("70,40,77,28,23,72,82,38,29")
```

Please note the quotes. It's still a string, which is a **single value** here. But to make it work, `IN()` would require it to be multiple values separated with commas:

```
a.staticdata_id in (70,40,77,28,23,72,82,38,29)
```

To make it work you can try with string function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function instead of `IN()`.

Try with:

```
FIND_IN_SET(a.staticdata_id, heroSdIds)
```

So the whole query would be:

```
SELECT SUM(a.comat) FROM ky_heroinfo a 
    WHERE a.uid = uid AND FIND_IN_SET(a.staticdata_id, heroSdIds)
```